# Uncaught TypeError: users.map is not a function .. mapping on function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

**When i first write the map function , the code  works fine. but all on a sudden this line throwing error . Then ifi comment the users.map line the code works just fine, then uncomment it , till that works fine. But when i reload the page the error again show up to console and nothing works**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState({});
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/users")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => setUsers(data))
  }, [])
  console.log(users);

  const handleAddUser = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const name = event.target.name.value;
    const email = event.target.email.value;
    const user = { name, email };
    // post data 
    fetch('http://localhost:5000/user', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(user),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('Success:', data);
      })
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Own API {users.length}</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleAddUser}>
        <input type="text" name='name' placeholder='name' required />
        <input type="text" name='email' placeholder='email' required />
        <input type="submit" value="add user" />
      </form>

      <ul>
        {users.map(user => <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>)}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Why is the users default value an object? `const [users, setUsers] = useState({});` <--

Comment: `.map` is for [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), but you initialize it to be `{}`

Answer (score 1):

This is because users is an object not an array, therefore trying to map over it will result in an error. Try either turning it into an array or map over the object's keys.

---

Option 1: Changing to an Array

```
const [ users, setUsers ] = useState([])
```

Then you can use the map

```
{ users.map( user => <li key={user.id}>{user.name}</li>
```

---

Option 2: Stick with an Object

```
{ Object.keys(users).map( key => <li key={users[key].id}>{users[key].name}</li>
```

Comment: Arrays are technically objects in JS, but could you add a snippet of code to clarify what you mean?

Comment: straight forward explanation would be, object doesn't have `.map` method. While array does have one. Please refer to the mdn documentation for further details